# Specifying a Webpage Icon Name/Title for Web Clip

Tags: ios, angularjs, ios5, web-clips

I am following this guide for Specifying a Webpage Icon for Web Clip

(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

However, I wasn't able to find how to change the default Name or Title displayed below on the icon on the phone. Anyone know how to change or set a default icon name?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Enter Your Name Or Title Here">
```

put this line in between your head tags in the index.html or your top level html.

Comment: I couldn't find this on the apple docs page but it works and is just what I was looking for! Without this, it defaults to the page title. But the page title is a little long for an app name on the home screen.